# How to get selected text everywhere with xcode

Tags: xcode, macos

I'm new with xcode developing. I can't find any **free** and **easy-to-use** translator on Mac OS, so I decide to write one myself.

The most important feature for this project is it can get text wherever in Mac OS, which means I can select the text in **Preview** when reading PDF files, either right-click-menu or system short-cut is ideal way to start my translator.

**My major question is how to get the selected text in xcode when waking up my translator?**
If you can tell me how to register global right-click-menu or short-cut, I would also be very grateful.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just write an app which registers itself as a Mac OS X **Service** (in the application Services menu) ? That will then interact with *any* Cocoa without any additional work. See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/SysServices/introduction.html for details.